# Why some files are read only for root by default?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, root

In Linux systems, the root user has privileges to change permission for every file. Then what is the logic of some files having read only permission for the root user by default?

File in concern: `/etc/resolv.conf`

[image]

Comment: you missed his `chmod 777 resolv.conf` command...

Comment: sorry @MattDMo I did see the chmod, but it doesn't mean anything in regards to root permissions. I was thinking about it wrong - I was thinking that the U of the UGO applies to root, but it doesn't. Root always has rw on files lie /etc/resolv.conf...

Comment: If your real problem is that the file is overwritten on boot, then please change this entire question, including the title, or ask a new one. Thanks.

Comment: @slhck how can i see the versions of my question so that i can post a new question out of my last unedited question ?

Comment: Click [the `edited…` link](http://superuser.com/posts/677320/revisions) where you find the other revisions. If you post a new question, you can of course link back to this one for clarification, but it's really a different issue. Next time, please always ask about the actual problem you're facing first. Thanks

Comment: I don't see a single file in the screenshot you have provided that is readonly for root user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `/etc/resolv.conf` has `-rw-r--r--` permissions, so it's not readonly for root. The root user has read *and* write access, as indicated by the `rw` part.

I should mention that it's a terrible idea to:

- … always run with elevated (root) privileges. Use the system as a normal user, and use `sudo` when you need to do something that requires root access.
- … `chmod` important system files to be world-writable (`777` as in `rwxrwxrwx`). This is completely unnecessary at best – and at worst it'd would make it easy for anyone (including yourself) to wreck your system by doing anything unthoughtful as a non-privileged user.

Comment: is root privilage indicated in the UGO? I think even if the U was r, root would still be rw. I thought root trumps user.

Comment: I just tried changing file permissions on a file to 000, and was able to edit the file in vi as root...

Comment: @BenPlont Yes, as root, you can still write to it and override it, but that's orthogonal to the "problem" the OP described. The mode does not actually determine whether the file is writable. Some editors including `vi` do not respect the mode and will try to overwrite regardless. Unless the file is on a read-only filesystem, doing so as root will succeed.